# How to calculate age-specific quartile

Tags: r, quantile

I want to calculate sex-specific age-specific quartile categories for energy intake among a large population.

Data like:

```
Age Sex    Engergy
18  Male   807
65  Female 1154
20  Female 759
43  Female 1674
#……
```

Data expected：

```
Age Sex    Engergy Category
18  Male   807     Q1
65  Female 1154    Q2
20  Female 759     Q1
43  Female 1674    Q4
#……
```

I have tried quantiles function. But I wonder how to calculate these after considering age and sex.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::ntile()` inside `mutate()`, with the [new `.by` argument](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-per-operation-grouping/) for per-operation grouping:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(
    Category = paste0("Q", ntile(Energy, 4)),
    .by = c(Age, Sex)
 )

dat
```

```
  Age    Sex Energy Category
1  27 Female   1283       Q3
2  22 Female   1108       Q1
3  24 Female   1065       Q2
4  29   Male   1239       Q2
5  25   Male   1477       Q4
6  25 Female   1213       Q3
```

Or, in dplyr version <1.1.0:

```
dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(Age, Sex) %>%
  mutate(Category = paste0("Q", ntile(Energy, 4))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

dat <- data.frame(
  Age = sample(20:30, 200, replace = TRUE),
  Sex = sample(c("Female", "Male"), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Energy = round(rnorm(200, 1200, 200))
)
```